# PHP cookie domain prevent setting the cookie

Tags: php, cookies

May be a stupid question, but google doesn't tell me that.

```
setcookie($key, $value, $time, '/', $domain);
```

This method I use to set a cookie. PHP doesn't set this cookie. Only after deleting $domain variable (string variable) it sets successfully.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Value of `$domain` needs to be same as your actual domain, then only browser will honor the cookie.

Comment: I use $_SERVER['server_name']. Does it fit here?

Comment: It might, it might not. Try creating a new php file with just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and see what fits your need.